# Magento 2 Block class instantiate issue

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts

I am using Magento 2.2.6. In my custom module I add `catalog_category_view.xml` add a block

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryListing"  name="sidebar.vendor.category" before="catalog.navigation.renderer" cacheable="false" template="Vendor_Module::category_list.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and class is as

```
class CategoryListing extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function welcome()
    {
        .....
    }
}
```

but page through error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:144 Stack trace: #0
```

But without class in layout xml as

```
<block name="sidebar.vendor.category" before="catalog.navigation.renderer" cacheable="false" template="Vendor_Module::category_list.phtml"/>
```

Works fine i.e. load `category_list.phtml` with its content. But my target is using the block with class.

Where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: can you please add your error here ?

Comment: I think you have written wrong. like class shows vendor\module and template file shows Vendor_Core. You can change the class and template path properly. What is the module name you are using?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryListing"  name="sidebar.vendor.category" before="catalog.navigation.renderer" cacheable="false" template="Vendor_Module::category_list.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
```

- Be sure your file `CategoryListing.php` located in
  `Vendor/Module/Block` folder
- Be sure `category_list.phtml` file located in
  `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates` folder
- Be sure your file `catalog_category_view.xml` located in
  `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout` folder

> May be you have made some spell-mistakes and capitalize like
>   `class="Vendor\Module\Block\CategoryListing"`

**EDIT**

Your constructor does not match the parent class constructor after seeing your error.

To fix that you need to update your constructor:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
 ) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
  }
```

Don't forget to flush the `var/cache` and `var/generation` after your changes.

Comment: All ok. I updated my question.

Comment: I edit my answer too